# solution to convert to/from SecureString for any strings that could contain ‘secure’ data

Tags: c#, wcf, security, dynamics-crm-2011

A code analysis tool (Fortify) flagged some string variables containing potentially secure data in my code as being vulnerable to heap inspection (because of the way .NET handles strings) and recommended conversion to `SecureString`.

From what I understand, the best way to deal with secure strings is with `byte[]` which is cleaned up when it goes out of scope, unlike strings. The problem is you have to implement any string-type methods (like `replace`, etc) for `byte[]`.

**What are the alternatives to using byte[] and rolling my own string methods?**

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

from the above link

Use appropriate members of the System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal class, such as the SecureStringToBSTR method, to manipulate the value of a SecureString object.

Comment: securestring scales very poorly, Not actually complete because as soon as you call ‘ToUnsecureString’ you have the same heap inspection issue with the resulting string returned from the method.

Comment: OK - I'll delete this as an answer soon but for my info by 'scales poorly', do you mean its useless as its no longer secure as soon as you try to actually use the stored string (which obviously you will do at some point)?

Comment: please leave your answer, perhaps the ToBSTR might help

Answer (score 0):

An application is vulnerable to Heap Inspection when sensitive information (you confirm the info is sensitive in your case) is stored as clear-text (unencrypted) in the memory.

If an attacker will perform a memory dump (remember the Heartbleed bug?), this sensitive information will be compromised.

There are two proper ways of holding such sensitive information:

- Using a secured object, such as a GuardedString instead of a String or a char array, or
- Encrypting the information and immediately scrubbing the memory containing the clear-text

It is advised to use one of these methods to hold your sensitive information securely.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple idea —— To be honest. SecureString is NOT ALWAYS of secure (I mean it's ONLY safe when you are NOT taking the value out and assign it to another string as a plain text!) So What we should do is to just Clear the memory ASAP when we don't wanna this string anymore! Something like this:

Persude Code:

```
public void ValidationUserInfo(string userName,string password)
{
    //Do validations with password, after converting it to secureString and fetch it out?....

    //Just clear the memory!
    ClearSensiveString(password);

    //Do any others or return after validations.....
}

//Your memory clear way:

static unsafe void ClearSensiveString(string sensiveValue,char coverChar='\0')
        {
            fixed(char* c = sensiveValue)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < sensiveValue.Length; i++)
                {
                    c[i] = coverChar;
                }
            }
        }
```